# Device eth0 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-kernel, network-interface

I have cloned a fedora and now trying to configure network interfaces. Every time i am adding a new NIC, it starts with number eth3 (rather eth0). i have tried removing and modifying the `70-persistent-net.rules` as well as the `network-scripts/eth0` but nothing seems to be fixing the issue. Here are some outputs from my machine

```
[root@abc ~]# ls /sys/class/net
eth3  eth4  lo  pan0
[root@abc ~]# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules 
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single line.

# PCI device 0x15ad:0x07b0 (vmxnet3)
#SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:29:29:7f:eb", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x15ad:0x07b0 (vmxnet3)
#SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:29:29:7f:ff", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"

# PCI device 0x15ad:0x07b0 (vmxnet3)
#SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:29:29:7f:f5", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

# PCI device 0x15ad:0x07b0 (vmxnet3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:29:a3:3e:16", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x15ad:0x07b0 (vmxnet3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:29:a3:3e:20", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

# PCI device 0x15ad:0x07b0 (vmxnet3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:29:a3:3e:2a", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"

[root@abc ~]# service network restart
Shutting down loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:  Device eth0 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
[FAILED]
[root@abc ~]#  
[root@abc network-scripts]# vi ifcfg-eth0 

# Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5721 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
HWADDR=00:0c:29:a3:3e:16
IPADDR=192.168.1.75
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
~
```

Any suggestions on how can i fix it?

Comment: Do you have a list of the MAC addresses that vmware is assigning to your VM?

Comment: ifconfig -a
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:A3:3E:16  
          inet addr:192.168.144.75  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fea3:3e16/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:40997 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:463 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2543682 (2.4 MiB)  TX bytes:65822 (64.2 KiB)

Comment: eth4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:A3:3E:20  
          inet addr:10.10.10.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fea3:3e20/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:198 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:196 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18378 (17.9 KiB)  TX bytes:20271 (19.7 KiB)

Comment: lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:72277 (70.5 KiB)  TX bytes:72277 (70.5 KiB)

Comment: pan0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:CB:63:1B:B6:10  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

Comment: Can you tell us the MAC address of the interface you wish to be seen as eth0 ?

Answer (score 5):

Empty `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`:

```
[root@xxxsat601 ~]# echo > /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
[root@xxxsat601 ~]#
```

and reboot. It should repopulate the file for you. This file exists so that if you insert a new NIC into a machine such that it appears to be `eth0` it doesn't take on your `eth0`'s IP configuration (if you omitted the mac address from the config) and is instead called by a new name.

If you truncate the file, there's no way for all that information to be in there unless that's really what the hardware configuration looks like.

Comment: I tried but its not repopulating....

Comment: Many udev implementations do not rebuild 70-persistent-net.rules if the MAC vendor portion is in a list that's considered to be used by popular virtual machine implementations.  00:0c:29 is one of them.

Comment: If it isn't repopulating then I'd check to see if it still created it as `eth0` even without the rules. Otherwise you should be able to just manually add the udev rule by copying/pasting the old `eth0` rule and just updating the MAC address portion.

Comment: if i am adding another NIC, it is adding as eth3 (even without the rules).

Comment: What version of fedora are you on? I've never seen that behavior before so I'd like to set up a reproducer on my side.

Comment: Linux ns71 2.6.25-FC9_32_CAV3 #17 SMP Mon Feb 15 12:24:31 PST 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: i have another vm that has same specs as this one and i was able to reset the ethernet numbers (by modifying the persistent rules and network scripts) on that but for some reason i cannot do it for this VM

Comment: What's the Fedora version if you do a `cat /etc/fedora-release` ? I'd still like to get a reproducer going to see if I can recreate the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Also, is NetworkManger running on the one that doesn't renumber the interfaces?

Comment: Fedora release 9 (Sulphur)

Comment: i am not sure about network manager...how can i check/confirm?

Comment: Try `chkconfig NetworkManager --list`

Comment: chkconfig NetworkManager --list
NetworkManager  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off

Comment: any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that maybe you need to update the base image you're cloning from. Fedora 9 was released back in 2008. They're currently on Fedora 21 (with Fedora 22 soon to be released). Outside of that, I would check the `modprobe` config or `/etc/rc.local` to see if anything complicated happened on this machine that would touch networking.

Answer (score 5):

When you boot to the cloned machine enter `ifconfig -a` you will see there is no eth0 but there should be an eth1. It is trying initiate eth0 because of the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.

To fix this, edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.  Remove the first block for eth0.  Change the second block to `NAME="eth0"`

Copy the MAC and replace the MAC in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and edit the IP if necessary.

Reboot the VM and you should be good to go. This worked for me.

Comment: Removing the first block and changing eth0 in the remaining block worked great for a VPS migration.